# How to add attributes to a raster stack

Tags: raster, r, loop, rasterstack

I have a dataframe ("DataGroup"), which holds tracking data from individual birds. Each bird has a unique id ("ID"), and belongs to one of 10 study groups ("DGroup").

In addition, I have a raster stack ("udstack"), which holds the rasters of multiple utilisation distributions - one for each animal. Each layer (each individual raster) is called after the ID of the animal, to which the utilisation distribution belongs. I want to add two attributes to each layer;

1. I want each layer to hold an attribute called "ID", which holds the name of the layer.
2. I want each layer to hold a second attribute called "DGroup", which is the name of the Group associated with the ID (as per the dataframe). Is this possible?

For background - The purpose of this is that I want to then average rasters from the same Group. The raster stack is the output from a function that (very annoyingly) does not allow me to keep the information from the DGroup from the outset (KDE, adehabitatHR).

Here are some dummy data to replicate my data structure:

```
# Create dummy dataframe
n <- 20
IDs <- paste0("ID", 1:n)
DGroups <- sample(c("G1", "G2", "G3"), n, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID = IDs, DGroup = DGroups)

# Create dummy raster stack
raster_list <- list()
for (id in IDs) {
  values <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 1), ncol = 10)
  r <- raster(values, xmn = 0, xmx = 1, ymn = 0, ymx = 1, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
  names(r) <- id
  raster_list[[id]] <- r
}
raster_stack <- stack(raster_list)
```

I tried the following:

```
# Attach attribute "ID" to the raster_stack
attr(raster_stack, "ID") <- names(raster_stack)

print(raster_stack)


# Check if the ID attribute corresponds to each layer 
for (i in 1:nlayers(raster_stack)) {
  layer <- raster_stack[[i]]
  layer_name <- names(raster_stack)[i]
  id_attribute <- attributes(layer)$ID
  cat("Layer:", layer_name, " - ID:", id_attribute, "\n")
}
```

--> no success. Where am I going wrong?